# Webpack multiple requires resolving to same file but being imported twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, require, webpack

Hello I just had this problem with webpack. If I do `require('../something')` from one file, and then I do `require('../../something')` in another file they both end up resolving to the same file. However if you look in the output bundle there are two different webpack functions both with the same content. I'm pretty sure I can use an alias to fix this and then just do `require('something')` in both files. But is this the right way to do it or am I missing something?

Btw I need this because it's causing several problems with angularjs undefining my controllers.

Comment: Well until I figure out if alias's are the right method to use. If you make an alias for the root directory of your javascript and prefix all your requires with that. Then use the absolute path instead of the relative path all your requires for a file become the same path and it fixes this issue. http://pastebin.com/R9jUAdTP

Comment: Can you create a mock webpack config and files with this issue ?

Comment: @BoopathiRajaa Maybe if you give me a template but I'm a bit busy. But making an alias for your base dir and always using that instead of relative paths fixes it. This has been working great for several months.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the DedupePlugin. It looks for if the module has already been included in your build and if so, doesn't include it again. It's easy to set up and you don't need to require or install anything extra.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    // more of your config
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent a module from being evaluated twice. It only ensures that only a single copy of the code exists (I tried, and someone else also confirms: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2134.